# Calculate the probability that sensor fails

Tags: probability

Knowing that i have 100 nodes . Iwould like to calculate thz probability of the node failing depending on the enegy parameter .
Which is the most suitable probability methods i this problem ?

Comment: The statement is too vague.  (node - energy parameter definition?)

Answer (score 0):

I'll solve a slightly different problem that will give you an idea. For example, you want to know the probability that at least one node fails. Assuming each node follows Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p$ (probability of failure), your sample is large enough to use CLT, since $\mu=p, \sigma^2 = p(1-p)$:
$$
P(S_n\geq1) =  P\bigg(\frac{S_n - np}{\sqrt{np(1-p}} \geq\frac{1-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}\bigg) \approx 1-\Phi\bigg(\frac{1-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}\bigg)
$$
where $\Phi$ is the CDF of standard normal distribution. Here $S_n$ is the sum of rvs, which is $0$ only if no node fails.